# Running cypress tests in parallel using docker

Tags: docker, automation, cypress

I am working on a cypress solution integrated with cucumber and I would like to execute tests in parallel in order to improve the execution time. I have no devOps knowledge so if somebody can help me with a tutorial or steps to do in order to try to run locally my tests in parallel it would be great. Thank you.

Comment: You can start here: https://docs.cypress.io/guides/guides/parallelization.html#Overview

Answer (score 0):

https://docs.cypress.io/guides/continuous-integration/introduction#What-is-Continuous-Integration and
https://docs.cypress.io/guides/guides/parallelization.html

On the CI part notice that they have examples for multiple pipelines, so you can customize on how they work. E.g., BitBucket works with docker containers, and they have a concrete parallel example for that

Answer (score 0):

Another possible option would be using [Moon](https://aerokube.com/moon/latest/#_using_cypress) where Cypress support was recently added. In that case you get uniform parallel execution of Cypress, Playwright and Selenium tests in the same solution.

Comment: Interesting.   I wonder if you still get reporting similar to Cypress Dashboard reporting flaky tests, etc.?   Probably not.

Comment: Moon is the runtime only. However you can use well know Allure (https://github.com/allure-framework/allure2/) report with Cypress. E.g. https://github.com/Shelex/cypress-allure-plugin-example

Comment: Also, I found that MochaAwesome works great with Cypress and is MUCH SIMPLER than using Allure.   In any case, turns out that using a CI plugin is required in order to get parallel runs along with the cypress cloud dashboard reporting.   Mochawesome is just supplemental to that.

Answer (score 0):

Another maybe not so popular option is to use TCMS with a good API, like [TestRail](https://www.gurock.com/testrail/docs/api/getting-started/accessing) (my team's current approach). This way all the test cases info aggregation and report visualisation will be done for you. All you need is to set `runID`, so all containers log dump to the right place. Plus, the management really liked some features like traceability matrix (i.e test coverage).